# Python 3: How can I check if two lists match even if elements are not in order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists:

```
original_list= [1,2,3,4,5]

new_list = [[1,7,3,4], [1,2,4,5,3]]
```

Other than using sort and then list in list, how can I compare the original_list values are in new_list?

Comment: sort the items of your list, not the list itself. `new_list = [sorted(x) for x in new_list]` should do it.

Comment: Why do you not want sort? Because it changes your original lists? Also, if the order doesn't matter for your collections, you may consider using `set`s rather than lists.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you require both lists to have the same elements with same multiplicity? Or just that each value in original list is also in new_list? That would be set inclusion discarding multiplicities. Or something still different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to sort each `list` in `new_list`, not `new_list` itself. Try this for instance using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
print(sorted(original_list) in map(sorted, new_list))
```

or if you only care for the existence of the same elements regardless of their count:

```
print(set(original_list) in map(set, new_list))
```

Comment: Or `sorted(original_list) in map(sorted, new_list)`

Comment: every time `map` is used purposedly in python 3 I'm happy.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You mean if it is not molested with some `lambda` expression?

Comment: @schwobaseggl exactly :) when a function already exists and you don't need a `list` it's the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

supposing your original list is already sorted (if not, just apply `sort`), you have to compare each element - sorted - using a loop or `any`:

```
new_list = [[1,7,3,4],[1,2,4,5,3]]
original_list= [1,2,3,4,5]
original_list.sort()  # optional if the list is not sorted yet

print(any(sorted(x)==original_list for x in new_list))
```

prints `True` if a sub-list of `new_list` has the same elements as `original_list`

That avoids to rebuild the original list using `new_list = [sorted(x) for x in new_list]` to get sorted items, since order may be important after all.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `sorted` which has `O(n*log(n))` runtime behaviour (worst case I think) you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (almost guaranteed `O(n)` runtime behaviour):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst_counts = Counter(original_list)
>>> any(lst_counts == Counter(sublist) for sublist in new_list)
True
```

That uses the fact that Counter compare both keys and values and therefore are only equal if the dictionaries (inside the `Counter`) are identical

If you can exclude duplicates then instead of `Counter` you can also use `set`s.